# Looking up a row in the same table - Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to lookup rows from the same table in Power Query, as I need to view the number of referrals from 3 months ago to calculate how many people are likely to be on the programme at that month.

This is a simplified example of what the table looks like:

```
Provider | Month  | Contract month  | Number of referrals | 
50505    | Jul-23 |        10       |          54         |
50505    | Jun-23 |         9       |          34         |
50505    | May-23 |         8       |          21         |
50505    | Apr-23 |         7       |          45         |
```

I have tried to create a lookup for three months ago (see below), so that I can use this as a lookup for three months ago. I have duplicated the table and then tried using merge queries, but this returns an error. Is there a way of doing this?

```
Provider | Month  | Contract month  | Number of referrals | Contract month 3 months ago   | Lookup-current month (Provider&Month) | Lookup-3 months ago (Provider&Month)   | 
50505    | Jul-23 |        10       |          54         |             7                 |      5050510                          |        505057
50505    | Jun-23 |         9       |          34         |             6                 |      505059                           |        505056
50505    | May-23 |         8       |          21         |             5                 |      505058                           |        505055
50505    | Apr-23 |         7       |          45         |             4                 |      505057                           |        505054
```

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark for answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It converts the text Month column into an actual date, then generates a column with the [3 months prior date] . It then merges on top of itself to get the Referrals from that older date

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Provider", Int64.Type}, {"Month", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", each Date.FromText([Month], [Format="MMM-yy"])),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "3MonthsAgo", each Date.AddMonths([Date],-3)),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom1", {"Provider", "3MonthsAgo"}, #"Added Custom1", {"Provider", "Date"}, "Added Custom1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Added Custom1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom1", {"Number of referrals"}, {"referrals_3ago"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Added Custom1",{"Date", "3MonthsAgo"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]